DropIt! Abbrevations Variables for .msg files (Outlook item)
I'd like to store my important emails in a folder structure. I plan to use DropIt! to move my emails to dedicated folders on my harddrive in the following structure using environment or file variables:
/Mails/%Sender_Name%/%DateCreated%_%Sender_Name%_%FileName%.msg

resulting in
/Mails/Harry Example/2024-07-01_Harry Example_New Message.msg

Does know anyone how to get the environment variable of the %sender_name% from a .msg file (and if this is possible)?
